# java.reflection ProceedingJoinPoint

Tags: java, aspectj

```
@Around("toSomething()")
public void check(ProceedingJoinPoint pJPoint){
    Object[] args=pJPoint.getArgs();
    makeSomeChange(args);
    pJPoint.proceed(args);
}
```

In the above case does the changes made in args be reflected in the invoking method.

What I am really asking is that will proceed pass this args to the method whose execution was intercepted by the AspectJ. Sorry for not asking it clearly.

Comment: what type of changes are you doing? What type of object does it contain?

Comment: Even after you updated the question the code is bogus. E.g. your pointcut is unclear. Provide a real example, please, optimally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) including an application class the aspect is applied upon. Another mistake is that you cannot pass anything to `proceed()` which has not been bound to a parameter in the pointcut. If you provide a real example I can provide a real solution. Pseudo code without relevant information just does not work here.

Answer (score 1):

No, in order for the values in the `args` array to be changed you would have to do:

```
args[0] = process(args[0]);
```

In Java you cannot change the value in an array by passing the value to a method, you have to pass the array, or modify the array after the call.

I don't know what your `change(...)` method does, but whatever it sets is not being put in the args array

Comment: If Object is of Student type and If I changes just it's name. In that case it will reflect the changes in original as well.

Comment: If args[0] is a 'Student' and you modify something in the `Student` then the student changes, yes, and since the student you pass in to 'change' is the same student instance as the one in `args[0]` then yes, `args[0]` will reflect the same change. Technically you are not making changes in `args` then, but in some value that happens to be stored in `args`

Comment: so it depends on the type of objects stored in array and the logic that is written in change() method?

Comment: Sorry guys the question i think was not formed well i have updated it please help.